# tc-angular-chartjs problems while assigning value to chart-data

Tags: angularjs, charts, chart.js

I want to set chart-data with a name stored in the array but its not working.
I stored array names into an array and assign name to chart-data with ng-repeat but chart-data not taking any names from the array it display none.it shows chart only if name is directly assigned.

```
<div  ng-repeat="x in data123">
<h4>{{x}}</h4>
<canvas tc-chartjs-doughnut chart-options="options1" chart-data=x auto-legend></canvas>
</div>
```

array is

```
$scope.data123=['basketballl','Dancee'];
```

this worked only if

```
<canvas tc-chartjs-doughnut chart-options="options1" chart-data=Dancee auto-legend></canvas>
```

how can I assign array value to chart-data

I also tried

```
chart-data={{x}}
chart-data="x"
```

none of them working

Comment: Have you tried `chart-data="{{x}}"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chart-data takes only array not array names that stored in array.if you want to use ng-repeat to show multiple graphs insert array for chat-data in another array with other datas.

```
$scope.data1.push({
    value: data.Group[i].Count[j],
    color: chartColor[j],
    highlight: chartColor[j],
    label: data.Group[i].options[j]
    }); 
$scope.groupDet.push({'groupid':data.Group[i].groupID,
                   'groupName':data.Group[i].groupName ,
                   'ff':$scope.data1
                 });

<div  ng-repeat="x in groupDet">
<h4>{{x.groupName}}</h4>
<canvas tc-chartjs-doughnut chart-options="options1" chart-data=x.ff auto-legend></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

chart.js initially accepts label and value properties only except colors and all.
 you need to change in script which is given by chart.js..
suppose your propery from array is xyz.. you need to craete a segment in script like segment.xyz like this or replace label with your property name

hope it vl helps